# Installing Ubuntu on Macbook, and sound issues are happening

Tags: nvidia, sound, soundcard

Just got a MacBook 2010 of amazon and looking to put Ubuntu on it.

I have no problem installing 19.10.

Also tried Mint-mate and everything works perfectly including sound.
19.10 Ubuntu works but the only thing that occurs is crackling tinny sound when playing music/youtube ext.

The sound card is good as it works with other distros but not 19.10 Ubuntu.
could this be a driver issue?

soundcard is HDA Nvidia cirrus logic C54200.